# ¿Por qué no me funcionan los col en Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, bootstrap-4

Estoy intentando hacer el típico sidebar a la izquierda fijo con height 100% en Bootstrap. Pero, si no le pongo un position fixed, el height no funciona. El problema llega cuando eso ocupa un `col-2` y la parte del contenido un `col-10`, pero no se me ponen bien y no se me ve el contenido de este.

Pongo código HTML y CSS:

```css
.body {
  background-color: #EDF1F5;
}

.sidebar {
  background: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 1px 0px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid row p-0 m-0">
  <div class="col-md-2 h-100 position-fixed bg-black sidebar">

  </div>
  <div class="col-md-10 p-0 m-0 body">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Tienes que usar ese  container-fluid aqui??    `<div class="container-fluid row p-0 m-0">` me parece que eso causa el problema

Comment: Después de ver la respuesta de Dev. Joel me ha surgido una duda: ¿el problema es que no se ve al 100% de altura o que el div con col-10 se monta encima del div con col-2? Porque parece que hemos entendido cosas diferentes. ¿Qué es lo que no se pone bien? ¿qué contenido es el que no se ve?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro yo entendí que quería añadir dos columnas con un `height:100%`  , pero para esto se veía obligado a utilizar una `position:fixed`  para que ocupe el  `100%`   lo cuál traía problemas, entonces mostré que esto no es necesario para conseguir un `100%` . quizá  entendí mal.

Comment: lo que quiero hacer es la barra de la izquierda con 100% de altura, y el col-10 normal ya que irán publicaciones, ademas, el col-10 se monta en el col-2, no se si me he explicado bien

Comment: @Dev.Joel Yo entendí que cuando el tamaño es md o más, el sidebar no se ve porque el body se pone encima.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro lo que estoy intentando hacer es como está en esta página: https://socialyte.codeplus.it/wall.html

Comment: @Dev.Joel lo que estoy intentando hacer es como está en esta página: socialyte.codeplus.it/wall.html

Comment: @MarioRamosGarcía añadí un ejemplo de la estructura básica del ejemplo que añade, aunque para su problema y el por qué de su problema la respuesta de Alvaro es la más adecuada.

Comment: @MarioRamosGarcía con el cambio que te pongo en el código obtendrías un resultado similar del sidebar.

Answer (score 3):

Una opción sería la siguiente: cuando el tamaño de la ventana se `md` haz que el `div` con tamaño 10 tenga un offset de 2 para que no se ponga sobre el sidebar. Eso lo puedes hacer añadiendo la clase `offset-md-2`. También tendrás que quitar la clase `m-0` que hace que el elemento tenga margen 0 y que crearía un conflicto con `offset-md-2`.

Aquí lo puedes ver funcionando:

```css
.body {
  background-color: #EDF1F5;
}

.sidebar {
  background: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 1px 0px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid row p-0 m-0">
  <div class="col-md-2 h-100 position-fixed bg-black sidebar">
    SIDEBAR!!
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-10 offset-md-2 p-0 body">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
    CONTENIDO!
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

No es necesario utilizar `position:fixed` para utilizar el `height` al `100%`, puedes setear mediante `CSS` al `html,body` al `100%` como en la [documentación](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/sizing/) para que haga efecto  la clase `h-100` .

Un ejemplo base  de acuerdo a su comentario sería

```css
html,body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container-fluid row p-0 m-0 h-100">
  <div class="col-md-2 h-100 sidebar">

      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/nyljaMXg.png" class="img-thumbnail rounded-circle mt-5" alt="Cinque Terre">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-10 p-0 m-0 body h-100 ">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <form class="form-inline">
          <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" aria-label="Search">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Búscar</button>
        </form>
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Menú <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Menú2</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container mt-3">
      <div class="row justify-content-center ">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">Ejemplo</h4>
                <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rem tenetur at ab, consectetur reiciendis veritatis sint nemo suscipit in voluptate cum, repudiandae recusandae dolor quod atque quisquam quas deleniti fuga..</p>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Si no mal comprendo, tu error se ocaciona porque tenes unas 2 columnas en fixed y otras columnas 10 de manera normal. Para crear una sidebar con el 100% del alto, no deberías usar % sino vh.

Viewport Units: https://css-tricks.com/fun-viewport-units/

Te dejo, como edite tu codigo para que veas como quedaría usando vh y otras pequeñas modificaciones.

```css
.body {
  background-color: #EDF1F5;
}

.sidebar {
  background: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 1px 0px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
}
.wrapper{
  height: 100vh
}

.navbar .navbar-custom{
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: row;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid row p-0 m-0 wrapper">
  <div class="col-2 bg-black sidebar">
    Sidebar
  </div>
  <div class="col-10 p-0 m-0 body">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark 
    inline">
        <ul class="d-flex navbar-custom navbar-nav mr-auto d-inline">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    Content to Page
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Para que la respuesta tenga mayor posibilidad de ser aceptada editala y haz un ejemplo. **Te invito a leer [answer]**